Why is the IRS asking about digital assets?
I noticed the IRS is always asking about digital assets for income tax but doesn't appear to do anything with it in any of the forms, at least the ones I deal with. On the 1040 we see the following question

Digital Assets
At any time during 2023, did you: (a) receive (as a
reward, award, or payment for property or services); or (b) sell,
exchange, or otherwise dispose of a digital asset (or a financial
interest in a digital asset)? (See instructions.) Yes No

Similar questions are found on earlier years (starting in 2020)

At any time during 2020, did you receive, sell, send, exchange, or
otherwise acquire any financial interest in any virtual currency? Yes
No
At any time during 2021, did you receive, sell, exchange, or otherwise
dispose of any financial interest in any virtual currency? Yes No
Digital Assets At any time during 2022, did you: (a) receive (as a
reward, award, or payment for property or services); or (b) sell,
exchange, gift, or otherwise dispose of a digital asset (or a
financial interest in a digital asset)? (See instructions.)

It seems like this question is going to follow us well out into the future. Why are we required to answer this, it feels like the IRS is turning the 1040 into a survey which something tells me it shouldn't be. So why is the IRS asking about this detail exactly? Is there any historical precedent to survey questions involving financial matters to show up in the 1040 and phase out? Is there a part somewhere in the tax forms that refers back to this line ("if you answered yes to ...")?

did you ever answer Yes to one of these questions while using tax software?

I don't use tax software but it's an interesting angle that could lend some connections that I am never otherwise exposed to. This hit came up searching for turbotax and digital assets: https://coinledger.io/blog/form-8949-for-cryptocurrency.  It's spot on with that form as there is a Digital Assets section in the instructions but not in the form itself: https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i8949.pdf. So at least there's a place for "Sales and Other Dispositions of Capital Assets".

Now that I look closer at the question, it only focuses on income changing events: receive (+income) or sell/exchange etc (also +income). They don't care if you merely bought and held these assets, just that there was some taxable event surrounding them now that I think about this a bit deeper.

2020 was the most fuzzy with the word "acquire" showing up, but you can see the language converging to focus on income oriented events only of which yes the IRS would wish to know about since the 1040 is after all income tax and they want to know about income in all its shapes and sizes.

The IRS added this question because people were not considering trading in digital assets as a taxable activity. In fact, in its origin, crypto currencies were peddled as a tax evasion scheme. Many people didn't think that they need to report conversions from BTC to ETH and such, because it's not shares of stock but something else. By adding the question the IRS is trying to emphasize that crypto assets are just as assets as any other and gains on them should be reported accordingly.

Adding to this, if you answer "no" when the truth is "yes", it might be easier for the IRS to put forward a case against you for evasion or fraud (if they ever find out). It might even allow them to get around the 3-year audit window and argue for the "no time limit in instances of fraud".

@StanH Yes this is precisely the case. There are other instances of 'gotcha' questions like this that the IRS has inserted into its forms, which exist primarily in an attempt to elevate 'tax mistake' to 'tax fraud'. It becomes much harder to defend that you 'didnt know you had to report x', when there is a question that asks explicitly: 'do you have any x to report?'

Do you have any references? (I guess IRS may not expressly state the purpose any way...)

@xuhdev see the history explained here
